# Material-table lookup does not work with a dynamically constructed variable

Tags: material-table

I am passing a variable constructed as the following code for Lookup.

```
let classLookup = {};
let classOptions = responseData.classOptions;
for (var i = 0; i < classOptions.length; ++i) {
    classLookup[i] = classOptions[i];
}
```

Here responseData.classOptions is an array:

```
[{0: "A"}, {1:"B"}....]
```

classLookup is then constructed as:

```
{0: "A", 1: "B" ....}
```

Passing classLookup to material-table does not get recognized.

```
{
    title: 'Class',
    field: 'Class',
    lookup: classLookup
},
```

However, if I hard coded classLookup as

```
let classLookup = {0: "A", 1: "B" ....}
```

It works fine.

I am clueless what was wrong with the variable I constructed. Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue found. I shall use useState to set classLookup.

```
const [classLookup, setClassLookup] = useState();
let tmp = {};
let classOptions = responseData.classOptions;
for (var i = 0; i < classOptions.length; ++i) {
    tmp[i] = classOptions[i];
}
setClassLookup(tmp)
```